# Minimize Standard Deviation of Group Outcome Probability?

Tags: probability, optimization, algorithms

I have a population of 60 that I need to group into groups of 6. There are two possible independent outcomes (A/B) for each member of the population, the probabilities of which are known.

My target (desirable) outcome for each group is: [Any outcome that is NOT 5A+1B or 1A+5B].

My initial idea to optimize would be to minimize the standard deviation of the outcome probabilities for the overall selection however the only way I can think of executing this is via brute forcing. Any guidance for alternatives would be very much appreciated.

---

## As a shortened example:

**Objective: Construct groups of 3, minimizing standard deviation. Undesirable is all die or all survive.**

### Population Data

| ID | p(Death) | p(Survival) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0.5 | 0.5 |
| B | 0.45 | 0.55 |
| C | 0.25 | 0.75 |
| D | 0.4 | 0.6 |
| E | 0.2 | 0.8 |
| F | 0.3 | 0.7 |
| G | 0.1 | 0.9 |
| H | 0.5 | 0.5 |
| I | 0.8 | 0.2 |

### Selection1

| Group | p(allDie) + p(allSurv) |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | 0.2625 |
| DEF | 0.3600 |
| GHI | 0.1300 |

Standard deviation of [p(allDie) + p(allSurv)] of Selection1= 0.1154

### Selection2

| Group | p(allDie) + p(allSurv) |
| --- | --- |
| ABI | 0.2350 |
| DEH | 0.2800 |
| CFG | 0.4800 |

Standard deviation of [p(allDie) + p(allSurv)] of Selection2= 0.1304

**Selection1 would be a better group selection as standard deviation of [p(allDie) + p(allSurv)] is lower.**

---

I apologize in advance for the lack of conciseness and lack of notation in my question as I am very unknowledgeable in this field.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with probability nor with standard deviation.  AS I understand it, you have the population results, right?  Doesn't matter how likely or unlikely they were.  It's just a question of sorting the people.  If you only have one $A$ (or only one $B$) then you can not do what you want.

Comment: One of the two types must have no more than $30$ instances, say it is $A$.  Write the number of $A's$  as $3n+\alpha$, and put $3$ $A's $ in each $n$ groups, distributing the $\alpha$ amongst those (at most one in each).  The cases $\#A=2$ and $\#A=5$ are easily handled separately.

Comment: @lulu Sorry if I am misunderstanding. The event which will cause A/B has yet to happen. The objective is to minimize the variance in probability of [5A+1B or 5B+1A] for each group for the overall selection.

Comment: But then I don't understand what you are asking.  If I have already created the groups, then I have no control over the outcomes.  I don't understand what choices are available to me.  Please edit your post for clarity (don't leave critical information for the comments).

Comment: @lulu Ok sorry I am in the process of writing an example. The groups are not created yet. The choices are which members of the population go into which group together to minimize the variance in probability of [5A+1B or 5B+1A] for the groups at the end of the selection process.

Comment: @lulu I added an example. Hope it adds some clarity.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Different members of the population have different probabilities.  That was not clear.  But the problem is still not cot clear.  You need to specify what objective function you are seeking to minimize.  From what you wrote I can think of a few:  you might want to minimize the bad outcome probability for your worst group.  Or you might want to minimize the expected number of bad outcomes.  And so on.  Changing the objective function is likely to change your answer.

Comment: Note:  whatever objective function you have in mind, it is likely that you will need to simulate outcomes.  Even computing the bad outcome probability for a single group is a pain, as there are $12$ bad scenarios to analyze.

Comment: @lulu Sorry for the lack of clarity I am not well versed in these types of problems. The objective is to minimize the expected number of bad outcomes. Would my initial idea of minimizing standard deviation not be suitable for this? Thanks for your replies.

Comment: I wouldn't think so, no. What I'd do:  try a random allotment and get all the bad outcome probabilities.  Then look at the worst groups.  If you have bad groups of each type (likely to get a single $A$ vs likely to get a single $B$), make swaps between those.  Otherwise consider swaps between good and bad groups.  Here, of course, I am thinking of an automated search for a solution.

Comment: Minimizing the SD will try to group samples so that each group has the *same* chance of the undesirable outcome, but won't *minimize* the chance of the undesirable outcome. You could group samples so that the chances of the undesirable outcome is (0.1, 0.1, 0.1) or (0.9, 0.9, 0.9), and the SD approach would treat those as equally good solutions. But if I understand correctly, the former would be far preferable, as each group has a lower chance of the undesirable outcome.